# Copilot Fails to Deploy Cannot Access SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I'm getting the follow error when I try to deploy my **Load Balanced Web Service** with **Copilot** into a new environment. I have everything running in `test`, created a new `prod` environment and tried to deploy the service into it, but the task details show a stopped reason of:

> ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth:
> execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secrets from
> ssm: service call has been retried 1 time(s): AccessDeniedException:
> User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSM parameters were added specifically for the `test` env, which I thought would apply by default to all environments, but apparently not. Had to add again for `prod` environment, with the tag `copilot-environment`.

```
aws ssm put-parameter \
    --name /copilot/applications/core/environments/test/port \
    --value '8000' \
    --type SecureString \
    --tags Key=copilot-environment,Value=test Key=copilot-application,Value=core
```

```
aws ssm put-parameter \
    --name /copilot/applications/core/environments/prod/port \
    --value '8000' \
    --type SecureString \
    --tags Key=copilot-environment,Value=prod Key=copilot-application,Value=core
```

And updated my manifest.yml:

```
secrets:                      # Pass secrets from AWS Systems Manager (SSM) Parameter Store.
  PORT: /copilot/applications/core/environments/test/port

# You can override any of the values defined above by environment.
environments:
  prod:
    secrets:
      PORT: /copilot/applications/core/environments/prod/port
```

Answer (score 0):

A more "standard" solution is to use the copilot secret init command :
`copilot secret init`

This will create the secret in your AWS **Systems Manager >
Parameter Store**